# GLPI 10 API REST On creation date setting problem

Tags: php, json, api, version

I am writing a php script that will transfer ticket from our previous ticketing solution to GLPI 10.

I made a first version for it while we were still on GLPI 9 and had no problem. But now, after the version change I can't set the "closedate" and "solvedate" of tickets I'm creating. I'd like to know if this is a new rule in GLPI 10 or if the way to do it changed. Or if anyone knows how to solve this problem

Here's an example of which route I call and what I pass to it :

[Image showing the route and JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bsai7.png)

Route : glpi.com/apirest.php/Ticket

Json passed :

```
{"input": { 
    "_users_id_requester":12,
    "date_creation": "2022-05-11 08:01:20",
    "closedate": "2022-05-12 08:03:09",
    "solvedate": "2022-05-13 08:03:09",
    "date_mod": "2022-05-14 08:03:09",
    "date":"2022-05-17 08:01:20",
 "content": "Ticket test GLPI10 pbm date",
 "users_id": 12, 
 "itilcategories_id": 25, 
 "name": "Test de pre set date", 
 "type": 1}}
```

Server's answer :

```
{
    "id": 15681,
    "message": "Élément ajouté : Test de pre set date"
}
```

But then in GLPI, the ticket's date are all replaced by the value of the "date" parameter. And if I send it without the "date" parameter it takes today's date as value.
The parameters I'm sending are the one I copied from the "GET Ticket" route.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with GLPI 10.
When I try to send a ticket using the API, if the field "date" is NOT set, all the date fields (date_creation, solvedate, closedate) are filled with the current date (the moment I send the API request).
I the field "date" IS set, all the date fields are filled with the same value as the "date" field.
I have tried various things, such as specifying or not the mod_date, or give in the duration of the ticket in the fields "close_delay_stat", with no result.

EDIT 16/01/2023 :  I sent a ticket some time after my post and the support answered me that it was indeed a bug, but to have it fixed I'd have to subscribe to multiple of their services

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33623612)